# Computing SMA in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I have just started to learn C++ and was wondering if anyone could help me to improve my function. I am making a basic statistical api and am calculating a SMA (simple moving average) for some data. This function provides the correct output but it is quite messy and convoluted I am sure.

I wanted to solve the problem before asking for help which is why it is probably such a mess but now I have solved it I would like advice on how I can improve it.

I am using a loop within a loop to create a sub-vector which I sum and divide to get my average. I did this because I could not get work out how to get accumulate to calculate the beginning and ending values via indexing so if someone can help me with this part in particular I would be grateful. But really any help would be appreciated.

I also got this pop up "The thread 0x76d0 has exited with code 0 (0x0)." I haven't really been able to find a good explanation other than it is a debug thing and you can press continue (Visual Studio)

```
std::vector <long double> SMA(std::vector <long double> &ARR, int lag) {
    std::vector<long double> sma_values;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR.size(); ++i) {
        if (i < lag) {
            sma_values.push_back(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());              
        }
        else {
            std::vector<long double> temp_vector;

            for (size_t n = 0; n < lag; ++n) {
                temp_vector.push_back(ARR[i - n]);
            }

            long double sum = accumulate(temp_vector.begin(), temp_vector.end(), 0.0, std::plus<long double>()); 
            long double average = sum / lag;
            sma_values.push_back(average);
        }
    }

    return sma_values;
}
```

Comment: Since this code is working it is probably a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is your definition of SMA, "Simple Moving Average"?  Sorry, but I don't know every acronym.

Comment: yes sorry I didn't specify